# folder named according to todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing some general VBA code that is working perfectly. But the issue is, I have a daily folder whose name is according to the todays date with 8 characters i.e. `10/01/2017` would be `12012017`.

so I tried various different formulas and the closest I could come to a solution was using the following in each cell

```
=DAY(TODAY())    - A1
=MONTH(TODAY())  - B1 
=YEAR(TODAY())   - C1
```

and setting the day and month to have to 2 characters in case it is 1 - 9 to be equivalent of 01 - 09. But the issue is when I combine the cells with "&" `( =A1 & B2 & C1 )` the zeros automatically disappear. Instead of printing `12012018` it shows `1212018`.

I am out of ideas, can someone please help

Comment: (Note that your date example has dropped a couple of days, and a year.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TEXT function, so `=TEXT(A1,"00")` will preserve a leading zero.

```
=TEXT(A1,"00")&TEXT(B1,"00")&TEXT(C1,"0000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (VBA code)

```
foldername = right("00" & day(now), 2) & right("00" & month(now), 2) & year(now)
```

Comment: I don't see why not ?!?

Comment: You need parens after NOW, but you could use TODAY() anyway as there is no time element requirement. (A small point, I know.)

Comment: My statement is VBA-code (as the OP was talking about VBA). I will add this in the post.

Comment: My apologies, the OP's question references VBA but uses formulas so this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can even make it in one line like this:

```
=TEXT(TODAY();"DDMMYYYY")
```